# program crashing once colors.xml added to the values folder android ant compile

Tags: android, xml, ant, colors, build

I'm very confused as to why my program keeps crashing when I add a colors.xml file to the values folder. It runs absolutely perfectly until I add this file and then the whole program wont load. I checked logcat *:E --->

E/AndroidRuntime( 6041): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{self.redway.dynamicfragment/self.redway.dynamicfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050000 for fragment FragmentOne{41e3d1b8 #0 id=0x7f050000}

When I checked in gen to see what 0x7f050000 it turned out to be the reference to a string held in strings.xml so it kind of looks like because I have added the colors.xml file ant is no longer parsing strings.xml.

But I'm not sure I'm very new to android and even newer to using ant (I didn't have this problem with eclipse).

Again I would stress I have made no change to my program or any of the code in it since it was running perfectly simple added this file in /res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#00F</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FF0</color>
</resources>
```

UPDATE

Here is the java code for FragmentOne if that helps:

```
package self.redway.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle, savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be `<item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>`?

Comment: Since you discovered that the ID is for a String resource, it sounds like you are calling `findViewById()` on something like `R.string.my_string`. Can you post the code for `FragmentOne` around where the Exception tells you the crash occurred?

Comment: Actually the only time the string is referred to is in the main.xml. It is the app name. So the program is crashing when it is called to do the original layout. Also I would again stress that the program works fine if I delete this colors.xml file and make no other changes.

Comment: Have put the code for FragmentOne as requested. Hope that helps?